# Python: test empty set intersection without creation of new set

Tags: python, set, intersection

I often find myself wanting to test the intersection of two sets without using the result of the intersections.

```
set1 = set([1,2])
set2 = set([2,3])
if(set1 & set2):
  print("Non-empty intersection")
else:
  print("Empty intersection")
```

The problem is that a new set is created to do this test which can be inefficient.

Is there a short way to do this without explicitly writing it out (as in the following)?

```
if(any(x in set2 for x in set1)):
  print("Non-empty intersection")
else:
  print("Empty intersection")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=sets#set.isdisjoint), as sets are [disjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets) if and only if they have an empty intersection.

```
>>> set1 = set([1,2])
>>> set2 = set([2,3])
>>> set1.isdisjoint(set2)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) to test wheather two sets have an empty intersection, just negate for the oposite:

```
set1 = set([1,2])
set2 = set([2,3])

if not set1.sidisjoint(set2):
  print("Non-empty intersection")
else:
  print("Empty intersection")
```